# how to check null values in linq left join condition insted in where condition

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am writing linq query that needs to get records from left table always event if there are are no records in right table. i wrote linq query for that.Right table may consist of null values in this case i am getting error.
how to check null condition in **on** clause instead in where clause. if i use where clause to check nulls it gets zero records but i need all the left table records.

```
 join sfs in db.SubmissionFileUploadSummaries on new { sub.CollectionId, districtid, tbl.Tablename } equals new { CollectionId = (int)sfs.CollectionId, districtid = (int)sfs.OrganizationId, Tablename = sfs.TableName }
             into sfslist
             from sfssub in sfslist.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where sfssub.CollectionId!=null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule for keeping the `left outer join` semantics is to apply the right table filter **before** the join:

```
join sfs in (from sfs in db.SubmissionFileUploadSummaries
             where sfs.CollectionId != null
             select sfs)  
    on new { sub.CollectionId, districtid, tbl.Tablename }
    equals new { CollectionId = (int)sfs.CollectionId, districtid = (int)sfs.OrganizationId, Tablename = sfs.TableName }
into sfslist
from sfssub in sfslist.DefaultIfEmpty()
```